# Datetimepicker не работает ни на локалке, ни на сайте, только в компиляторе stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я уже принял готовое решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035730/bootstrap-date-time-picker,  загрузив datetimepicker. это работает в локальной компиляции stackoverflow, но в моем локальном хосте xampp есть только панель со значком, и все. Я не знаю, в чем ошибка, пожалуйста, помогите мне data.js

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>OCTYPE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script rel="javascript" href="/data.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

можете протестировать сами naveki.pro/test/index.html
оригинальный тред здесь  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195785/datetimepicker-doesnt-work-in-my-localhost?noredirect=1#comment120527180_68195785

Comment: Для начала перенесите теги `link` в `head` где им и место, а теги `script` в конец `body` (data.js как минимум). Возможно, скрипт выполняется до появления элементов в DOM

Comment: @NikitaUmnov поменял, изменил код, посмотрите пожалуйста. А что в data.js изменять?

Comment: зачем порядок скриптов изменили? data.js должен быть в конце, после подключения всех библиотек

Comment: @NikitaUmnov data.js подключается! И он в конце index.html! Я поменял как вы говорили link в head и script в конец body

Comment: Объясните мне кто-нибудь прошу почему в компиляторе stackoverflow это работает. а у меня ни на сайте, ни на локалке нигде не работает?!!!! У меня нету уже сил, прошу хоть кто-нибудь помогите

Comment: ха) не заметил сразу) поменяйте `href` на `src`

Comment: @NikitaUmnov когда поменял
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
 на src вообще даже иконка перестала показываться

Comment: ну а теперь правильный путь к файлу укажите `./data.js`

Comment: в скрипте src должен быть, верните link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>OCTYPE</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
     </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="./data.js"></script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: НИКИТА БРАТ ТЫ СПАС ЖИЗНЬ ЧЕЛОВЕКУ СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ БРАТАН ЧТОБЫ ВСЕ БЫЛО АХУЕННО!!!!

Comment: @OttovonBismarck ахах) пожалуйста)

Comment: А как русскую раскладку поставить? locale:ru не помогает ..